# How to add views while using a function in a separate class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I created a new `Swift-file` with a class which holds a function which should add some `UILabels`, `UITextFields` and an `UIButton` to the `viewcontroller`. 
When this code is in the `ViewController` it works, but in the separate file I get some error messages:

```
class InitialiseLabels {
    func setupLabels() {

        // multiple variables are declared without problems, but then:
        let viewWidth = view.frame.width // Use of unresolved identifier 'view'
        let viewHeight = view.frame.height // Use of unresolved identifier 'view'
        view.addSubview(myLabel) // Use of unresolved identifier 'view'

        // etcetera

        myTextField.delegate = self as" UITextFieldDelegate // Use of unresolved identifier 'self'
        view.addSubview(myTextField) // Use of unresolved identifier 'view'
    }
}
```

I guess that I should add something in front of view to specify where it should go (like `self.view` but that one obviously doesn't work, the name of this `ViewController` also doesn't work). Can somebody please help me?

Comment: In other file you want to access some other VC's view how it will be possible !! you can't do this.

Comment: @vivekDas Do you have another suggestion for me? I programmaticaly created `UILabels` and `UITextFields`. They should re-initialise after a `buttonAction`. That's why I created a function for the initialisation, but I if I place it after the `viewDidLoad` it's not available in the `buttonAction` code which comes after the `viewDidLoad`. That's why I moved it to a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
class InitialiseLabels
```

To

```
extension ViewController
```

Even if this is in another file, it has to be part of the original ViewController class, not some other class.

Comment: This is it!!! It works! Thank you so much! And sorry to everybody else if I wasn't clear in my questions!

Comment: But you should never have moved this code to another file in the first place.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions how to make it more elegant, but untill then, I'm very happy that I got my app to do what I want it to do!

Comment: I can’t make a suggestion because you have not shown enough code. Your statement “but I if I place it after the viewDidLoad it's not available in the buttonAction code which comes after the viewDidLoad” makes no sense, and you do not explain or demonstrate what it is supposed to mean. You have a fundamental misunderstanding and you should have asked about that.

Comment: Dear Matt, you are right, I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding, but in such a degree that I cannot explain what it is... I would be happy to send you my whole project if you would like to have a look!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question "How to add views while using a function in a separate class in Swift?" is "Don't do that."

You should treat a view controller's views as private. The view controller should be responsible for them.

If you really wanted to let an outside object add views to your view controller (again, you shouldn't do that) you'd need a reference to the other view controller. It would be cleaner to create a function that would take the new views as parameters and add them for the caller:

```
public func addViewdToContent(_ views: [UIView])
```

Then from the other object, you'd need a reference to that view  controller:

```
let otherViewConroller = //code to somehow get the other view controller. 

let contentView = otherViewConroller.view
let viewWidth = contentView.frame.width
let viewHeight = view.frame.height
otherViewConroller.addViewToContent([myLabel]
```

Your next line doesn't really make sense, and neither does the error you're getting. It is a **very bad idea** to make some other object the delegate of a view controller's views. It is **also** a bad idea to inject views like text fields that need delegates into another view controller.

```
myTextField.delegate = self as" UITextFieldDelegate // makes no sense
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I'm new to Swift so trying to learn and obviously breaking all the rules doing so. So my solution doesn't work. How can I then re-initialise the labels that I programmed after the buttonAction?

Comment: Actually, reading your answer again, maybe I wasn't clear. I didn't create a new view controller, just a new file with a function that should re-initialise the labels. Because that function is in a separate file, I have it available in the viewdidload and also in the buttonAction.

Comment: "re-initialize the labels?" What does that mean? Install new values in the labels?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a singleton of the swift file and then refer to the singleton while calling the functions that add the UILabel, UIButton etc. to your current view controller

Suppose following is the swift file

```
class ButtonCreator : NSObject {
   //Declare the Singleton
   static let shared = buttonCreator()

   func thisFunctionCreatesandReturnAButton(withFrame: CGRect) -> UIButton {
       let button = UIButton(frame: withFrame)
       return button 
   }
}
```

Now you can refer it throughout your application (any view controller) as

```
self.view.addSubview(ButtonCreator.shared.thisFunctionCreatesandReturnAButton(withFrame:CGRect(0,0,100,44)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Could you please elaborate? I don't really understand what I should do.

Comment: Answer updated. Let me know if it works out for you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `MyView` and assign that to VC's Main View. And put your code inside that class.

```
class MyView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // add code to align view properly
    }

    private setup() {
        ....

        let viewWidth = frame.width // Use of unresolved identifier 'view'
        let viewHeight = frame.height // Use of unresolved identifier 'view'
        addSubview(myLabel)

        myTextField.delegate = self as" UITextFieldDelegate // Use of unresolved identifier 'self'
        addSubview(myTextField) /

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong: I put the declaration of the function in the viewdidload and because of that it was not available in the other parts of the view controller. Because of that I wanted to put it in a separate class or extension but I realised now that the solution is to put the function declaration right after the view controller class declaration.